# Best way to put data in multiple places in firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am not so much familiar with firebase database,
I want to store data in target1, if that succeeds then will put some data to target2.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
Database.ref('target1').push({
  name: name,
  email: email
})
.then(()=>{
   Database.ref('target2').push().set({
     name: name,
     email: email
   })
   .then(()=>{
      console.log('success')
   })
})
```

Is this the correct way to store data in target1 and target2?
How can I catch error if target1 or target2 fails?

Comment: as @Frank van Puffelen said in his answer, you have to use multi path update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach works, but it means you're writing it in two calls. So the write to `target2` may fail after the write to `target1` succeeds.

If you want both of them to succeed or fails as one operation, you'll want to use a multi-location update. To get the exact same result as your current code with a multi-location update, it'd be something like:

```
var key1 = Database.ref('target1').push().key;
var key2 = Database.ref('target2').push().key;
var updates = {};
updates["target1/"+key1] = {
  name: name,
  email: email
};
updates["target2/"+key2) = {
  name: name,
  email: email
};
Database.ref().update(updates)
   .then(()=>{
      console.log('success')
   })
})
```